# I am submitting form by using post method but i am unable to get the value from input field. How I can get the value

Tags: php, forms, input, label, codeigniter-3

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("miner/miner_logins"); ?>">
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="demail" id="email">
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"> <br>enter code here
<input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="LOG IN" class="btnlogin">
<p align="center"><a href="#">Forgot Password? Reset enter code heret via the Website</a></p>
</form>
```

**its my controller in codeignite code**

Comment: in your controller method `miner_logins` try to ` echo $this->input->post('demail', TRUE); die;`

Comment: I wish they had a manual

Comment: @AlivetoDie I just posted answer, you can see difference between my comment and an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your form to persist the input values, closely see `set_value` part, for more information visit [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("miner/miner_logins"); ?>">
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="demail" value="<?php echo set_value('demail'); ?> id="email">
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"> <br>enter code here
<input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="LOG IN" class="btnlogin">
<p align="center"><a href="#">Forgot Password? Reset enter code heret via the Website</a></p>
</form>
```

Inside `miner.php` file write below method `miner_logins`

```
public function miner_logins(){
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('demail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
     $this->load->view('miner_logins_view');
  }else{
    // set required session here and do redirection to user page.
  }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but hope this will help you to learn how form submission should be handled in CI.

Answer (score 0):

In your `miner_logins` of your class `miner`, you can get the values like this as below that may help you.
Always try to assign it by creating variable for better code structure.

```
if($this->input->post())   // Before getting the values, check with this
{
    $demail   = $this->input->post('demail', TRUE);
    $password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);

    echo $demail; // You will get the value of demail.
    echo $password; // You will get the value of password.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$var_1 = $this->input->post('demail', TRUE);
$var_2 = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
```